# convert a dictionary of list to a dictionary of dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I have two dictionaries of slightly differing formats and I want to convert one to look like the other so that I can compare them easily. Any pointers to help acheive this would be appreciated.

```
Dict 1 --> {Key:[{key 1 : value: 1, key 2: value2}, {key 3: value 3, key 4: value 4}]}

Dict 2 --> {Key: { VALUE : [{key 1 : value: 1, key 2: value2}, {key 3: value 3, key 4: value 4}]}}
```

Comment: You should at least provide minimal dictionaries we can easily replicate, instead of pseudo-dictionaries with syntax errors

Comment: as @user3483203 suggest^

Answer (score 2):

It seems the only difference between the two dictionaries is that the second one has an extra dict with key `VALUE`. You could change it to look like the first one by executing:

```
dict2[Key] = dict2[Key][VALUE]
```

If you want to change the first dict to look like the second one, you could execute:

```
dict1[Key] = {VALUE: dict1[Key]}
```

Comment: I think you want `VALUE` there, not `'Value'`. Presumably `VALUE` is some constant or variable in the OP's code that they aren't showing us. The odds that it happens to have exactly the value `'Value'` are pretty low, and, while it's obvious to me what you meant, the odds that someone who asked a question like this will figure that out seem even lower…

Comment: Also might be worth showing how to go the other way with `dict1['Key'] = {VALUE: dict1['Key']}`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dict2[Key]=dict2[Key][VALUE]
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking `dict_1`'s structure to be the one you want (might be easier to use):

```
d_3 = {}

d_3[key] = dict_2[key][VALUE]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the first dict to the second dict by executing this:

```
dict3[Value]=dict1[Key]
dict2[Key]=dict3
```

Comment: This would change the data in dict2 which doesn't seem to be what the OP wants.